# Cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances on get method

Tags: laravel

For my api's, I want to notify the owner of a community everytime a comment is posted in a post that belongs to his community and my code looks like this, and the function looks like this:

```
public function communityPostComment(Request $request, $post_id) {
    $user = $this->getAuthorizedUser($request->header('X-User-Auth-Token'));
    $user = User::find(6999);
    if (!$user) {
        return response()->json(['error' => true, 'code' => 401, 'message' => INVALID_AUTH_TOKEN], 401);
    }

    //$text = $request->input('comment_text');
    $text = "This is my latest";

    if (is_null($text) || $text == '') {
        return response()->json(['error' => true, 'code' => 400, 'message' => 'No comment text submitted']);
    }

    try {
        if(0 && \App::environment('production-trigger')) {
            $insert = \DB::connection('trigger')->table('tbl_Community_Post_Comments')->insertGetId([
                'User_ID' => $user->id,
                'Post_ID' => $post_id,
                'Comment_Text' => $text,
                'Created_Date_Time' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'Active' => 1,
            ]);
            $post = \DB::table('community_custom_posts')->wherePostId($post_id)->first();
            $community = Community::whereUserId($post->community_id);
            event(new SendPostCommentNotification($community, $user));

        } else {
            $insert = CommunityPostComment::insertGetId([
                'post_id' => $post_id,
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'comment_text' => $text,
                'active' => 1,
                'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ]);
            $post = \DB::table('community_custom_posts')->wherePostId($post_id)->first();
            $community = Community::whereUserId($post->community_id)->get();
            event(new SendPostCommentNotification($community, $user));




        }
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'code' => 200, 'comment_id' => $insert]);
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => true, 'code' => 400, 'message' => 'Unsuccessful comment attempt', 'error_message' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```

This is how my route looks like:

```
Route::post('post/comment/{post_id}', 'GolfPlayed\APIController@communityPostComment')->where('post_id', '[0-9A-Za-z\-]+')->name('api.communityPostComment');
```

When I type this:

```
http://productionapi.local/post/comment/613
```

For some reason, I get a methodnotallowedexception

I see this in my screen too:

```
public function get($method = null)
{
    return is_null($method) ? $this->getRoutes() : Arr::get($this->routes, $method, []);
}

/**
 * Determine if the route collection contains a given named route.
```

Updated:
After changing my method from post to get, I get a different error.

```
$community = Community::whereUserId($post->id);
```

And this is what I intend on returning:

return response()->json(['success' => true, 'code' => 200, 'comment_id' => $community]);

But when I refresh the page, I receive an exception:

```
error_message   "You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances"
```

Comment: What do you mean with "When I type this:" are you opening it manually in the browser? You have defined the route with the `post` method so you can only access it with a POST request. If you want to open it manually in the browser you have to change it from  `post` to  `get`.

Answer (score 0):

Http method is `POST`
You can do post request with REST Client like Postman
https://www.getpostman.com/

Updated:
You forget to call `->get()` or `->first()`

```
$community = Community::whereUserId($post->community_id)->get();
```

Comment: question has been updated and previously given the same answer

Comment: Updated: You forget to call ->get() or ->first(), answer updated.